# Run AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess blocking

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In my app I want to ask for camera access when the user pressed a camera button, which would take him to an AVFoundation based camera live preview.

That view is presented using a "present modally segue".

So in my ViewController I currently override the `shouldPerformSegue()` and return true if the user gives permission or has granted it already, otherwise false.

If the user didn't grant access I am showing an Alert in which he can go to settings to change the permission. That is done in `showPermissionInfo()`.

My problem is, that `AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess` is called asynchronously and thus `hasCameraPermission` is not set to true before I'm checking for it.
Is there a way to call these restriction accesses in a blocking way?
Thank you!

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {

    if identifier == "Modally_ToCameraViewController"
    {
        var hasCameraPermission = false

        if AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) ==  .authorized
        {
            hasCameraPermission = true
        } else {
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video, completionHandler: { (granted: Bool) in
                if granted {
                    hasCameraPermission = true
                } else {
                    hasCameraPermission = false
                }
            })
        }


        if(!hasCameraPermission){
            showPermissionInfo()
        }

     return hasCameraPermission
    }

        return true

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy solution would be to create a semaphore and wait on it until the completion closure is called. `semaphore.wait` will block the current thread until `semaphore.signal` is called.

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video, completionHandler: { (granted: Bool) in
    if granted {
        hasCameraPermission = true
    } else {
        hasCameraPermission = false
    }
    semaphore.signal()
})

semaphore.wait()
```